# How to read the content from userNotificationCenter - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, push-notification

How to read the value of "magazin"?

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let action = response.actionIdentifier
        let request = response.notification.request
        let userInfo = request.content.userInfo

        if action == "open.magazin" {
            var str: String?
            let magazin = userInfo["magazin"]
            print("MAGAZYN : \(magazin)")

        }
        completionHandler()
 }
```

Function return value:

```
MAGAZYN : Optional({"pages":100,"size":"50 MB","productId":"com.sad","purchased":false,"coverImageURL":"","cat":3,"itemPrice":"4,99","fileURL":"","id":5,"title":"test","demoStartPage":0,"desc":""})
```

Comment: It's a JSON `String` - lots of examples about reading JSON in Swift, including `Codable` and `SwiftyJSON`

Comment: I tried to use swifty json but it does not work.

Comment: I can not cope with this message: "Can not convert value of type 'Any?' to expected argument type 'Data' "

Comment: `if let magazin = userInfo["magazin"] as? String { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 provides very powerful JSON parsing out of the box.  My favourite blog is [Ultimate Guide to JSON Parsing with Swift 4](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/), as I don't get to do it often enough and it covers many of the "gotchas" in a simple way.

So, I took you data, threw it into a playground and using...

```
let userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any] = ["magazin": "{\"pages\":100,\"size\":\"50 MB\",\"productId\":\"com.sad\",\"purchased\":false,\"coverImageURL\":\"\",\"cat\":3,\"itemPrice\":\"4,99\",\"fileURL\":\"\",\"id\":5,\"title\":\"test\",\"demoStartPage\":0,\"desc\":\"\"}"]

struct Magazin: Codable {
    let pages: Int
    let size: String
    let productId: String
    let purchased: Bool
    let coverImageURL: String
    let cat: Int
    let itemPrice: String
    let fileURL: String
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let demoStartPage: Int
    let desc: String
}

if let magazin = userInfo["magazin"] as? String {
    let jsonData = magazin.data(using: .utf8)!
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let mag = try! decoder.decode(Magazin.self, from: jsonData)
    print(mag.pages)
    print(mag.size)
    print(mag.productId)
    print(mag.purchased)
    print(mag.coverImageURL)
    print(mag.cat)
    print(mag.itemPrice)
    print(mag.fileURL)
    print(mag.id)
    print(mag.title)
    print(mag.demoStartPage)
    print(mag.desc)
}
```

Was about to output

```
100
50 MB
com.sad
false

3
4,99

5
test
0
```

**NOTE** I've used forced unwrapping in the example above, I expect you to clean it up and make appropriate use of `guard` and `do-catch`

> I can not cope with this message: "Can not convert value of type 'Any?' to expected argument type 'Data' "

So, two things, the `userInfo` is a `[AnyHasable: Any]` style dictionary, so the first thing you need to do is convert the value to an appropriate type, which is likely a `String` based on your example...

```
if let magazin = userInfo["magazin"] as? String {
    //...
}
```

Next, you need convert the `String` to `Data`

```
if let jsonData = magazin.data(using: .utf8) {
    //...
}
```